# Docker container can't communicate

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file with two services, one called module which runs an HTTP server and one called dashboard which runs a frontend interface that uses API endpoints on the server. This is what the docker-compose file looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:

  module:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - "./logs:/logs"

  web:
    build: ./dashboard
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
```

Occasionally, the dashboard should send requests to the module, so I'm sending GET requests (in node). I tried many different URLs but none of them seem to get a response. I tried:

- `http://localhost: 5000`
- `http://module:5000`
- `http://module`

None of these seem to work. Am I doing something wrong? Which URL should the requests be sent to? Are they not working because of a chrome security issue for example?

Comment: Can you please upload output (screenshot) of 'docker ps -a' command.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest a few things, let me know which one works for you.

1.As you are exposing port number 5000 (for the front-end and backend), then you should be simply able to communicate using IP address.

- http://ip_address_of_host_machine:5000

2.If you decided not to expose port number as security risk then in the docker-compose file you need to link both containers to each other and then by using container names you should be able to communicate.

```
version: '3'
 services:
  module:
   build: .
   ports: 
    - "5000:5000"
   links:
    - module:web
   volumes:
    - "./logs:/logs"
  web:
   build: ./dashboard
  links:
    - web:module
   ports: 
    - "3000:3000"
```

And inside your web docker container, you should be able to access backend using **http://module:5000**

**Note** - **module** will work only from inside docker container, if you want to access outside then use host machine ip address.

let me know if you need any help with this?

Comment: I can't use the IP address because these containers are supposed to work on any server without my explicit editing (of the IP in the code). And docker [advises](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) against using links because they are outdated.

Comment: In that case you need to create your own docker network, and need to run all containers on same network.

Comment: That already happens by default. See the first paragraph [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Answer (score -1):

You need to [EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#expose) the port on the module.  This will tell it to listen from within Docker (port is from outside, e.g. from your browser)

```
module:
 build: .
 expose: 
  - "5000"
...etc
```